# Hard disk does not show any Partitions during windows installation

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, installation, uefi

I have a samusung laptop 365e which ive been using for over a year now, it's been working well but it started freezing all of a sudden during it execution. it then finally refused to boot but instead, it would start and show a plain black screen. With suggestions i got, i tried;
1. Check the boot devices in the UEFI firmware (BIOS settings as most refer to) and there was a hard disk.
2. Installing a fresh windows 8.1 which starts well but does not show me any hard disk partitions on which to install windows.
3. When i take the hard drive to another computer it works perfectly and even allows complete installation.
4. When i try putting another hard disk to my computer it installs perfectly.

i'm reqesting for your advice on anything i can do to make this hardisk work for my laptop or should i just buy a new hard disk?

Comment: If they drive works in another PC then buying a new HDD wouldn't really solve anything because there isn't anything wrong with the HDD.

Comment: If the drive shows no partitions but still does show up as a drive, there's the question of what does it show up as? And what does it show up as in BIOS?

@Ramhound: It is quite possible (though not  common) for a hard drive that has a fault that causes it to work in one computer but not another. Requiring more power than usual to start up, which a laptop won't provide but a desktop will, or being excessively vulnerable to voltage dips is an example.